# Compute $ \int _{|z|=1} z^{-1+i} dz$ using the branch of log defined in {${z:0 <\arg (z) < 2\pi}$}

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

I was seeing this question and I have no ideia about how to start. Could you help me?

Compute $ \oint _{|z|=1} z^{-1+i} \,dz$ using the branch of log  defined in {${z:0 \le \arg (z) < 2\pi}$}

The solution given is $i(1-e^{-2\pi})$

Comment: It depends on the value you choose for $\log(1)$. Now $f(z) = z^{-1+i}$ is analytic on $\gamma(t) = e^{i t}, t \in (0,2\pi)$. Take $F$ such that $F' = f$ then $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = F(\gamma(2\pi))-F(\gamma(0))$.

Answer (score 0):

With the branch cut chosen along the positive real axis we write $z=e^{i\phi}$, $\phi \in [0,2\pi]$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=1}z^{-1+i}\,dz&=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{e^{i\phi}}e^{i\log(e^{i\phi})}\,ie^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=i(1-e^{-2\pi})
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: You used the branch of $\log$ analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$ **and** $\log(-1) = i\pi$

Comment: @reuns Indeed.  We are evaluating on $|z|=1$ for $0 \le \phi <2\pi$.  The endpoints of that contour don't implicate $\log(-1)$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Please feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.  And Happy Holidays!